# Matrix notation equivalent to using contravariant metric tensor with dot products of vector to extract out components of the vector

Tags: tensors

$$\begin{bmatrix} Z^{11}&  Z^{12} & Z^{13} \\
  Z^{21} &  Z^{22} &Z^{23} \\
 Z^{31} & Z^{32} & Z^{33} \\ \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \vec{v} \cdot e_1 
\\ \vec{v} 
\cdot e_2 \\
 \vec{v} \cdot e_3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \\ v_3 \end{bmatrix}$$

The above relation is equivalent too:

$$ Z^{ij} \vec{v} \cdot e_j = v_i$$

And, I can write: $\vec{v} \cdot Z^{ij} e_j  = v_i$ and I could use defnition of dual basis to make it $\vec{v} \cdot e^i= v_i$.

What would the linear algebra action equivalent to the simplification that I have done in the indical tensor notation here?

Note : $e_i$ are basis vectors. More context in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4133289/688539)

Comment: What are you looking for, beside $e^i=Z^{ij}e_j$?

Comment: @J.G. I had made a typo there. Basically what I want is to represent the simplification I made using tensor notation into matrix notation.

Comment: So something like $\vec{v}\cdot Z^{ij}e_j=v_i=\vec{v}\cdot e^i\implies Z^{ij}e_j=e^i$?

Comment: Yes, those steps in matrix notation @J.G. The first into second step is meaning that we do the action of matrix on a column with entries e_1, e_2,e_3. The dot product each entry of the resulted vector with $v$.. but I am a bit confused on how to show this using matrices

Comment: Actually this post was for me to complete a step in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4133289/688539). So maybe that will put more context on what I'm looking for @J.G.

Comment: Thanks for that context. It sounds like the tricky part is proving if $\vec{v}\cdot\vec{a}=\vec{v}\cdot\vec{b}$ for all vectors $\vec{v}$ then $\vec{a}=\vec{b}$. Equivalently, if $\vec{v}\cdot\vec{w}=0$ for all vectors $\vec{v}$ then $\vec{w}=\vec{0}$. I don't think focusing on matrix notation is the best approach to that.

Comment: @J.G. Yes that's more or less the idea but the reason I want to understand how to do it in the matrix notation, so I can get an insight on how to visualize the tensor expression in matrix form (also for teaching purposes because I think, tensors are more relatable if we show the same expressions work in linear algebra)

Comment: I would say I think the most tricky part is figuring out how to show the action pushing in the contravariant metric tensor to multiply the basis in the equation in matrix format